# Metric name for "Count of dead-lettered messages in a Queue/Topic. (Preview)" Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

For our continuous deployment, we want to set up alert rules for deadlettered messages in a topic. On azure portal, this metric exists as a preview feature. We would like to create this alert rule via ARM templates.

Is there a metric name already that I can use for this in my ARM template parameters?
If not, when will it be possible to use this metric in our ARM templates?

Please see metric name is not listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftservicebusnamespaces

But it is possible to manually create an alert rule and select this metric:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the ARM Template for Creating Metric Alert `Count of dead lettered messages in a Queue/Topic`:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "alertName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the alert"
      }
    },
    "alertDescription": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "This is a metric alert",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Description of alert"
      }
    },
    "alertSeverity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 3,
      "allowedValues": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Severity of alert {0,1,2,3,4}"
      }
    },
    "isEnabled": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies whether the alert is enabled"
      }
    },
    "resourceId": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Full Resource ID of the resource emitting the metric that will be used for the comparison. For example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.compute/virtualMachines/VM_xyz"
      }
    },
    "metricName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the metric used in the comparison to activate the alert."
      }
    },
    "operator": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "GreaterThan",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Equals",
        "NotEquals",
        "GreaterThan",
        "GreaterThanOrEqual",
        "LessThan",
        "LessThanOrEqual"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Operator comparing the current value with the threshold value."
      }
    },
    "threshold": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "0",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The threshold value at which the alert is activated."
      }
    },
    "timeAggregation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Average",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Average",
        "Minimum",
        "Maximum",
        "Total"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "How the data that is collected should be combined over time."
      }
    },
    "windowSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "PT5M",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Period of time used to monitor alert activity based on the threshold. Must be between five minutes and one day. ISO 8601 duration format."
      }
    },
    "evaluationFrequency": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "PT1M",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "how often the metric alert is evaluated represented in ISO 8601 duration format"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/ActionGroups",
      "name": "testAG12",
      "location": "Global",
      "kind": null,
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "testAg",
        "enabled": true,
        "emailReceivers": [
          {
            "name": "emailservice_-EmailAction-",
            "emailAddress": "email@contoso.com",
            "status": "Enabled",
            "useCommonAlertSchema": false
          }
        ],
        "smsReceivers": [],
        "webhookReceivers": [],
        "itsmReceivers": [],
        "azureAppPushReceivers": [],
        "automationRunbookReceivers": [],
        "voiceReceivers": [],
        "logicAppReceivers": [],
        "azureFunctionReceivers": [],
        "armRoleReceivers": []
      },
      "identity": null
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('alertName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
      "location": "global",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "description": "[parameters('alertDescription')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('alertSeverity')]",
        "enabled": "[parameters('isEnabled')]",
        "scopes": [ "[parameters('resourceId')]" ],
        "evaluationFrequency": "[parameters('evaluationFrequency')]",
        "windowSize": "[parameters('windowSize')]",
        "criteria": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "name": "1st criterion",
              "metricName": "[parameters('metricName')]",
              "metricNamespace": "microsoft.servicebus/namespaces",
              "dimensions": [],
              "operator": "[parameters('operator')]",
              "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]",
              "timeAggregation": "[parameters('timeAggregation')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/ActionGroups', 'testAG12')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Pass the below important values to the parameters:

```
Metric Name : DeadletteredMessages
Time Aggregation : Average
Resource Id: Resource ID of your Service Bus Namespace. You can get this from the properties of the service bus blade as shown in below image
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please let me know how you got to the screen from the second screenshot (with Settings) on the portal? Or in other words, how did you find the Metric Name? Then I can learn better how to find other metric names when I need them.

Comment: The second screenshot is actually a template deployment from the portal. 
Login to https://portal.azure.com > All Services > Search for Template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal#deploy-resources-from-custom-template

You can paste the template mentioned in my answer and you will see the same UI.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I forgot about "Export Template" feature in Azure portal. Upon manually creating the alert rules or any resources, resource group can be exported as ARM template. Here I was able to locate to resources that contain template content to generate the manually created resource.

[image]